# How to get the IP that mixpanel event came from?

Tags: ip, analytics, mixpanel

Is it possible to get the IP address that mixpanel event "came" from?

Either using their webapp or custom reports or API - any method would be helpful.

Or maybe we can extract the first/last IP address for the user (profile)?

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

I just got an email from Mixpanel support.

Apparentaly the IP is only used for geolocation purposes and is not stored automatically. So there's no way to retrieve the IPs from which the events were tracked.